# Javascript recursion variable scope

Tags: javascript, variables, recursion, scope

I have a recursive function(see code), if i start with depth 5

When branch

```
execute(depth-1,x,y,width/2,height/2);
```

finishes, depth is not 5 for

```
execute(depth-1,midX,y,width/2,height/2);
```

but 1, and it produces mess. You can see algorithm here: http://jsfiddle.net/g4p66/

It supposed to produce something that looks like a maze(a poorly designed maze, hah)

```
    function execute(depth,x,y,width,height){
        if(depth > 0){
            var midX = (x+width)/2;
            var midY = (y+height)/2;
            c.save();
            c.beginPath();
            c.moveTo(midX,midY);
            var from = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
            if(from === 0){
                c.lineTo(midX,y);
            } else if(from === 1){
                c.lineTo(x+width,midY);
            } else if(from === 2){
                c.lineTo(midX,y+height);
            } else if(from === 3){
                c.lineTo(x,midY);
            }
            c.stroke();
            c.restore();
            execute(depth-1,x,y,width/2,height/2);
            console.log(depth);
            execute(depth-1,midX,y,width/2,height/2);
            execute(depth-1,x,midY,width/2,height/2);
            execute(depth-1,midX,midY,width/2,height/2);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
I was reading console.log wrongly, so it got me confused.
The main reason is my midX midY calculation was wrong, should be:

```
var midX = (x+(x+width))/2;
var midY = (y+(y+height))/2;
```

Comment: i don't understand the question, what is wrong, my jsfiddle isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a variable scope problem but a problem of logic in interpreting the log.

The first `console.log` you see isn't the one at the top level of the recursion but the one at the deepest level, because that's the execution order.

Here's what happens :

```
execute(5)
   execute(4)
      execute(3)
         execute(2)
            execute(1)
                execute(0) : depth <=0 -> return
            console.log(depth) -> logs 1
```

You can check on your own screeshot that you're deep in the recursion when you get to the log :

[image]

Comment: Its not the problem, the problem is this: http://puu.sh/9bDFH/00d235f406.png
As you can see, the depth is 1 and not 4 right after the first execute  brach is finished

Comment: Look at the call stack on the right of your screenshot : you're deep into the recursion, not at the top level.